# How to handle multiple combination of Java bean validation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-validator

I've use case where I've to validate certain fields with different combination, I'm using `javax validation` API in my spring. Please find my list of fields `String name;` `String type;` `String userId;` `String userAltId;` `Date userBuyDate;` `Date userSellDate;`

**Input param conditions are:**

- `name, type and gender` -> Always required field
- `userId, userAltId` -> Either `userID` or `altID` should have value or both
  can have value
- `userBuyDate, userSellDate` -> If `userID` or `altID` is null, then
  `userBuyDate` and `userSellDate` must have values

**Pseudo if condition**

```
if (user.getName().isBlank() || user.getName().isEmpty() &&
        user.getType().isEmpty() || user.getType().isBlank() &&
        user.getGender().isEmpty() || user.getGender().isBlank()) {

    if (user.getUserId().isEmpty() || user.getUserId().isBlank() ||
            user.getUserAltId().isEmpty() || user.getUserAltId().isBlank() ||
            user.getUserSellDate() == null && user.getUserBuyDate() == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("input validation failed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("validation success");
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to apply these combination of validation in Java bean using javax validation API, please find my code below. Can someone please help how can I achieve these combination of validation with sample example. In my current code for all the fields I'm using `@NotNull` annotation, I don't know how to use the combination of optional and required annotation in the Java bean. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**User.java**

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Type cannot be null")
    private String type;

    @NotNull(message = "Gender cannot be null")
    private String gender;

    @NotNull(message = "User ID cannot be null")
    private String userId;

    @NotNull(message = "User Alt ID cannot be null")
    private String userAltId;

    @NotNull(message = "User Buy Date cannot be null")
    private Date userBuyDate;

    @NotNull(message = "User Sell Date cannot be null")
    private Date userSellDate;


}
```

**Test.java**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();

        // Always mandatory field
        user.setName("test");
        user.setType("Admin");
        user.setGender("Female");

        // Either userID or altID should have value or both can contain value
        user.setUserId("U1213");
        user.setUserAltId("UA93093");

        // If userID or altID is null, then userBuyDate and userSellDate are mandatory
        user.setUserSellDate(new Date());
        user.setUserBuyDate(new Date());

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
        for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) {
            System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
        }

        /*if (user.getName().isBlank() || user.getName().isEmpty() &&
                user.getType().isEmpty() || user.getType().isBlank() &&
                user.getGender().isEmpty() || user.getGender().isBlank()) {

            if (user.getUserId().isEmpty() || user.getUserId().isBlank() ||
                    user.getUserAltId().isEmpty() || user.getUserAltId().isBlank() ||
                    user.getUserSellDate() == null && user.getUserBuyDate() == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("input validation failed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("validation success");
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Can what you're looking for be done with _validation groups_?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you need to create your own validation annotation to be applied to your `User` class as whole.

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidUser {
    String message() default "Invalid User data.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Mind the `@Constraint(validatedBy = UserValidator.class)`. This means that you now need to implement `UserValidator` that will in fact validate your `User` object:

```java
public class UserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidUser, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String name = (String) new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue("name");

        // Your custom logic here
    }
}
```

Finally, the last thing is to use the custom annotation to your `User` class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@ValidUser
public class User {
    (...)
}
```

You could have more advanced annotation that would accept parameters, but I decided to show the simple solution as it seems to me that this is what you need. You can find an example of this at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator#custom-class-level-validation.